# Force Oracle to process one row at a time

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query that in the select statement uses a custom built function to return one of the values.

The problem I have is every now and then this function will error out because it returns more than one row of information.  SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

To further compound the issue I have checked the table data within the range that this query should be running and can't find any rows that would duplicate based on the where clause of this Function.

So I would like a quick way to identify on which Row of the original query this crashes so that I can take the values from that query that would be passed into the function and rebuild the Functions query with these values to get it's result and see which two or more rows are returned.

Any ideas?  I was hoping there could be a way to force Oracle to process one row at a time until it errors so you can see the results UP to the first error.

Added the code:

```
FUNCTION EFFPEG
--Returns Effective Pegged Freight given a Effdate, ShipTo, Item
  DATE1 IN NUMBER -- Effective Date (JULIANDATE)
  , SHAN IN NUMBER -- ShipTo Number (Numeric)
  , ITM IN NUMBER -- Short Item Number (Numeric)
  , AST IN VARCHAR -- Advance Pricing type (varchar)
  , MCU IN VARCHAR Default Null --ShipFrom Plant (varchar)
) RETURN Number
IS
  vReturn Number;
BEGIN

    Select ADFVTR/10000 
    into vReturn 
    from PRODDTA.F4072 
    where ADEFTJ <= DATE1 
    and ADEXDJ >= DATE1 
    and ADAN8 = SHAN and ADITM = ITM 
    and TRIM(ADAST) = TRIM(AST) 
    and ADEXDJ = (
        Select min(ADEXDJ) ADEXDJ 
        from PRODDTA.F4072 
        where ADEFTJ <= DATE1 
        and ADEXDJ >= DATE1 
        and ADAN8 = SHAN 
        and ADITM = ITM 
        and TRIM(ADAST) = TRIM(AST));
```

Query that calls this code and passes in the values is:

```
select GLEXR, ORDTYPE,
 EFFPEG(SDADDJ, SDSHAN, SDITM, 'PEGFRTT', SDMCU), 
from  proddta.F42119
```

Comment: This is not what you asked for, but SELECT DISTINCT gets around the problem you mention. Without seeing what your function looks like it is hard to say how to we can help you.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to add error logging to the function so that it logs the specific parameters it was called with when the error was encountered.  In addition, be aware that since SQL is set-based, it is entirely legal for Oracle to execute a function for rows that are later filtered out by `WHERE` clause predicates.  So you can't necessarily just look at rows that are ultimately returned by the query.

Comment: @igr I didn't add code because the question was not about how to fix my code to not return the "duplicates" the question was how to identify the data that causes the issue.  The code is fine, the Data should never be in a position to return two sets of information if it does it is a problem with the data and how it was generated and or entered and I need to identify the problem data so that I can correct it.

Comment: @JustinCave I'm trying to avoid touching the function, the function is in Production and to make changes to it I have to go down the road of QA and sign off and what not.  I was hoping for a way to identify the issue without moding the function. if I have to I can add the exception code and go down that path though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is trough Exceptions.

What you need to do is to add the code to handle many rows exception in your function:

```
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
         INSERT INTO ERR_TABLE
         SELECT your_columns 
         FROM query_that_sometimes_returns_multiple_rows
```

In this example the doubled result will go to separated table or you can decide to simply print out with dbms_output.

An easy page to start can be [this](http://psoug.org/reference/exception_handling.html), then just google exception and you should be able to find all you need.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Or, just dump the parameters and whatever else is needed to DBMS_OUTPUT. Yes, debugging via DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE *is* just so '70's, but sometimes the simplest solution is the quickest solution.  YMMV.